# cordova-plugin-device se puede obtener numero de serie para ios desde una app movil con ionic 1

Tags: ios

Estimado, no he logrado capturar el numero de serie de un ipad  con el plugin cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1, Se puede capturar?
Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido, para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta por la comunidad te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Al numero de serie único del dispositivo, el que se encuentra en itunes,necesito obtener ese numero para poder identificar el ipad desde una app móvil creada con ionic v1. he intentado con el uuid, pero se actualiza una vez que elimino la aplicación y la vuelvo a instalar.

Answer (score 1):

Segun la documentación del plugin [Device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/):

Puedes obtener los siguientes datos:

- device.model
- device.platform
- device.uuid
- device.version
- device.manufacturer
- device.isVirtual
- device.serial

De esta simple manera

```
var string = device.serial;
```

Sin embargo, dentro de la documentación recalcan que esta función esta solo para sistemas Android y OSX. Por lo tanto en iOS no funcionará.

Comment: Claro pero en un ios "ipad 2", me aparece con undefined, y en android  si me muestra el numero de serie, de esta forma lo estoy haciendo                                       var Nserie = window.device ? device.serial : '';
            alert(Nserie)

Comment: Ojo, que la documentación dice claramente que `serial` es disponible en Android y en OSX, no en IOS

Comment: muchas gracias, por eso nunca me mostraría el numero serial en ios, te agradecería si tiene alguna idea de obtener un numero único de ios para poder implementar en mi app. saludos

Comment: Utiliza `uuid`  para poder obtener el identificador unico

Comment: Si  esa fue mi primera opción , pero se presento el problema que este uuid cambia una vez se vuelve a instalar la app, y  propósito de mi app, es administrar los ipad y que cada ipad mande el estado de batería a una aplicación web.

Comment: Por casualidad tu aplicacion lleva algun tipo de login?

Comment: si es autentificado

Comment: también encontré este pluging lycwed-cordova-plugin-udid 1.0.0 "UniqueDeviceID", que se supone que no se debe cambiar el uuid aunque se desintale, pero tengo que subir la app a la tienda para verificar si es asi.